# Проблема при запуске проекта на django

Tags: python-3.x, django, postgresql, psycopg2

В первый раз запускаю проект на джанго.
psql установлен.
при вводе команды python manage.py migrate
выходит это

```
(venv) PS C:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Neobis_Auth_Project-master> python manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Neobis_Auth_Project-master\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Neobis_Auth_Project-master\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 33, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Neobis_Auth_Project-master\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 200, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Neobis_Auth_Project-master\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 33, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Neobis_Auth_Project-master\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 187, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Neobis_Auth_Project-master\venv\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Neobis_Auth_Project-master\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Neobis_Auth_Project-master\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Neobis_Auth_Project-master\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Neobis_Auth_Project-master\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Neobis_Auth_Project-master\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Neobis_Auth_Project-master\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Neobis_Auth_Project-master\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 89, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Neobis_Auth_Project-master\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 75, in handle
    self.check(databases=[database])
  File "C:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Neobis_Auth_Project-master\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 419, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "C:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Neobis_Auth_Project-master\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 76, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "C:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Neobis_Auth_Project-master\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\model_checks.py", line 34, in check_all_models
    errors.extend(model.check(**kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Neobis_Auth_Project-master\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 1303, in check
    *cls._check_indexes(databases),
  File "C:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Neobis_Auth_Project-master\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 1695, in _check_indexes
    connection.features.supports_covering_indexes or
  File "C:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Neobis_Auth_Project-master\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Neobis_Auth_Project-master\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\features.py", line 92, in is_postgresql_11
    return self.connection.pg_version >= 110000
  File "C:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Neobis_Auth_Project-master\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Neobis_Auth_Project-master\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 329, in pg_version
    with self.temporary_connection():
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\contextlib.py", line 135, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Neobis_Auth_Project-master\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 603, in temporary_connection
    with self.cursor() as cursor:
  File "C:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Neobis_Auth_Project-master\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 33, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Neobis_Auth_Project-master\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 259, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "C:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Neobis_Auth_Project-master\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 235, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "C:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Neobis_Auth_Project-master\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 33, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Neobis_Auth_Project-master\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 218, in ensure_connection
    with self.wrap_database_errors:
  File "C:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Neobis_Auth_Project-master\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Neobis_Auth_Project-master\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Neobis_Auth_Project-master\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 33, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Neobis_Auth_Project-master\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 200, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Neobis_Auth_Project-master\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 33, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Neobis_Auth_Project-master\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 187, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Neobis_Auth_Project-master\venv\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError
```

python manage.py makemigrations перед этим делал.
psql работает нормально

UPD:
Пароль почему то не правильный. Хотя обновил через суперюзера на 1234.

```
postgres=# ALTER USER Ramil WITH PASSWORD '1234';
ALTER ROLE
postgres=#
postgres=# \q
PS C:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Neobis_Auth_Project-master> psql
Password for user Ramil: 
psql: error: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: ВАЖНО:  пользователь "Ramil" не прошёл проверку подлинности (по паролю)
PS C:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Neobis_Auth_Project-master>
```

settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for auth project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.2.13.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/
"""
import os
import datetime
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '#'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'authentication.User'
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework_simplejwt.token_blacklist',
    'drf_yasg',
    'corsheaders',
    'authentication',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'auth.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'auth.wsgi.application'


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'auth_db',
        'USER': 'auth_username',
        'PASSWORD': 'auth_password',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'NON_FIELD_ERRORS_KEY': 'error',
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    )
}

SIMPLE_JWT = {
    "ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME": datetime.timedelta(minutes=60),
    "REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME": datetime.timedelta(days=1),
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
import os
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')


# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = '3'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '3'
    # os.environ.get('EMAIL_HOST_USER')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '3'
    # os.environ.get('EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD')

CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True

CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
    'http://localhost:3004',
    'http://127.0.0.1:3004'
]
```

Comment: `python manage.py makemigrations` создает файлы для миграции, которые помогают обновить структуру базу данных, а команда `python manage.py migrate` в свою очередь уже обновляет саму базу. У вас по видимому нет подключения к ней (базе данных), возможно логин пароль неверно ну или еще что-то. Убедитесь что у вас работает база данных и верно установлен логин и пароль.

Comment: Покажите Settings.py

Comment: чек upd plssssss